# Manage User - Custom

Tags: azure-devops

When I try to change user role in Azure DevOps, the user is always added to "Custom" even if I try to add to "Project Contributors". Do you have any idea where "Custom" come from and why I cannot add to Project Contributors.

[image]

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer, how did it go with this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see the user is added to *Custom* is because this user is also in some other groups than **Contributors,Readers and Administrators** group in this project.

Since this user is not only in Contributors group, he/she will have some other permissions inherited from other groups. Then it will show the user is added in **Custom** as what you see in above screenshot.

The way to fixed this is to remove this user from other groups. See below:

1, Go to **project settings**-->**Permissions** under **General**-->Go to **Users** tab-->Select **this User**-->Go to **Member of** tab--> To check what other groups **of this project** this user is also in --> Select this other group and click remove to this user from this group **of this project**

[image]

2, If you have done above step and it still shows this user is in **Custom** even if you tried to add to "Project Contributors". Most likely the Contributors group of this project is added to other groups than **Project Valid Users** group.

Go to **project settings**-->**Permissions** under **General**-->Select **Contributors** group-->Go to **Member of** tab--> remove **Contributors** group from other groups

[image]

**Note:**

However, i do not suggest you follow above steps to remove this user from other groups. Because it will cause this user losing the some permissions inherited from other groups.

And you donot need to wrong about the user is added to **Custom** even when you tried to add to **Contributors** group.

When you tried to add this user to Project Contributors. You can go the **project settings** ->**permissions** page. You will see this user is indeed added to the Contributors group of this project, even it is still showing **Custom**.